# Pushing an entire folder to local Git repository

Tags: git, git-push

I have this local directory `/Users/OSX/Documents/Git/` where I initialized as my git by `git init`.

How can I push an entire library e.g. `/Users/OSX/Documents/Project/Test` to my git repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copy `/Users/OSX/Documents/Project/Test` into your actual git repo so it can be tracked
2. change directory into `/Users/OSX/Documents/Git`
3. `git add Test` to add the Test directory to be tracked by git
4. `git commit -m "Added Test to repo"` to commit it to the repo

Comment: `/Users/OSX/Documents/Project/Test` will just be my backup. So if make changes to my original Test directory, do I need to do numbers 1-4 again?

Comment: The files need to live within the repo to be tracked. That should be the area you are modifying files over time.

Comment: But what if messed up my project? Is it going to affect the one I pushed?

Comment: I don't follow. Your git repo is tracking changes to the files for which is contains. You would make changes and commit them over time, building up revisions. At any point, you can revert those changes to an earlier date. The repo saves the changes. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: `You can revert those changes to an earlier date. The repo saves the changes.` this one.

Comment: One quick question. How do I revert, and how do I update the changes in my git repository?

Comment: You should check out http://git-scm.com/book. But once items are tracked, you can commit changes by adding and commit like above. Reverting is a bit more involved as there are different ways to revert. You might want to get yourself a GUI app to help. For OSX, I use SourceTree (in the appstore)